# Calling a stored function using postgres dblink

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I am trying to execute a function dev.dev_support_process in a different database of same instance using the dblink

```
select 
 * 
from 
   dblink('port=5432 dbname=dev host=postgres.database.azure.com user=dev@pgsql-dev-db password=dev123' , 
'SELECT * FROM dev.dev_support_process ( ''support'' )');


Also tried the same command with dblink_exec.

Getting the same error from the functions exceptional part. Can anyone help me on this.

Postgres version 11.4

I tried but getting below error.

ERROR: function dev_support_log_message(character varying, unknown) does not exist HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. CONTEXT: while executing command on unnamed dblink connection PL/pgSQL function dev.dev_support_process(text) line 26 at PERFORM

dev_support_log_message is the function called inside the dev_support_process as a exception part.

I verified the user is having access to execute the function and can execute manually. I am getting the error only when I am trying from this dblink.

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Where is the error message? (in plain text)

Comment: This is the error I am getting
ERROR:  function dev_support_log_message(character varying, unknown) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
CONTEXT:  while executing command on unnamed dblink connection
PL/pgSQL function dev.dev_support_process(text) line 26 at PERFORM

Comment: Please edit your question to format it properly, and put the error in the question rather than the comments.  You seem to have two statements, but they are not set off from each other and it isn't clear where they end or begin, or why there are two of them.

Comment: The error is about the function dev_support_log_message(). And that function is not in your code

Comment: I just edited with more details, please have a look and let me know any mistakes I made in the syntax.

Comment: is also missing a column definition list on your query, the error message could be wrong, happens very often,asl added newer string definitions : 
select 
 * 
from 
   dblink('port=5432 dbname=dev host=postgres.database.azure.com user=dev@pgsql-dev-db password=dev123' , 
$query$ SELECT * FROM dev.dev_support_process ( 'support' );$query$) AS (id bigint , description text ,etc boolean) ;

Comment: Finally I solved the issue.
The issue is all about the schema and function owner. I altered the ownership to same user, then works as expected.